# Do Frenzys/cookie multiplyers add to the amount of cookies Wrinklers drop?

Tags: cookie-clicker

Okay this is quite tricky. But, for example if I clicked on a **Golden Cookie** and got a **x7 multiplyer**, and (**while the x7 multiplyer is active**) **pop a wrinkler**, **does the ammount of cookies I would regularly gain increase by 7x?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. The amount of cookies gained from popping a wrinkler is not affected by the multipliers (or, for that matter, the clotting), or the "Click Frenzy (x777)" ones that can also appear.

The number of cookies leeched by the wrinkler (and thus returned when popped) is, however, affected by these multipliers.